# Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: powershell

I have some problem with Get-Date command, and I am getting error:

```
 Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "29/01/2020 00:00:00" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

my part of code:

```
$CEST = 7200
        $CSV = Import-Csv -Path "D:\1.csv"  -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object -SkipLast 2
        $CSV | ForEach-Object {

         $_.'Scheduled Start Date' = $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date $_.'Scheduled Start Date').ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
       $_.'Scheduled End Date' = $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date $_.'Scheduled End Date').ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s")) 

           $_.'Actual Start Date' = 
                If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.'Actual Start Date')) {
                      $_.'Actual Start Date' = ""
            }

                 ElseIf(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.'Actual Start Date')) {  

                 $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date $_.'Actual Start Date').ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
                   $_.'Scheduled Start Date' = $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date $_.'Actual Start Date').ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))    
                       }


           $_.'Actual End Date' = 
                If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.'Actual End Date')) {
                      $_.'Actual End Date' = ""
            }

                 ElseIf(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.'Actual End Date')) {  

                 $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date $_.'Actual End Date').ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
                 $_.'Scheduled End Date' = $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date $_.'Actual End Date').ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))

                       }  


} 
$CSV | 
Export-Csv -Path "D:\1_tmp.csv" -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Dates are keep in 1.csv file in format as below in columns in many rows (Scheduled End Date,Scheduled Start Date,Actual End Date, Actual Start Date)

```
27/05/2020 07:00:00
```

When I run Get-Date command on computer then output is:

```
Wednesday, May 6, 2020 2:59:59 PM
```

Please support!

Comment: You can try to parse the date as given in the CSV file with `[datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)`

Comment: I added, 
`CEST = 7200
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path "D:\1.csv"  -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object -SkipLast 2
[datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
[datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual End Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
[datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Scheduled End Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
[datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Scheduled Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)

$CSV | ForEach-Object {
 ......`but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, You want to convert date strings in a CSV written with format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` to Unix timestamps with an added `$CEST` timezone value.

Instead of repeating the same long construct, I would recommend using a small helper function to do that:

```
function Get-TimeStamp ([string]$dateString, [int]$offset = 0) {
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($dateString)) {
        $epoch = [DateTime]::new(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Utc')
        $date  = Get-Date ([datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null))
        $diff  = (Get-Date $date).ToUniversalTime() - $epoch
        return [int64]([Math]::Floor($diff.TotalSeconds) + $offset)

        # OR use the -UFormat way like
        # $date = Get-Date ([datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)).toUniversalTime() -UFormat '%s'
        # return [int64]$date + $offset
    }
}
```

Below that function, the code would look like this:

```
$CEST = 7200
Import-Csv -Path "D:\1.csv"  -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object -SkipLast 2 | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject] @{
        'Scheduled Start Date' = Get-TimeStamp $_.'Scheduled Start Date' $CEST
        'Scheduled End Date' = Get-TimeStamp $_.'Scheduled End Date' $CEST
        'Actual Start Date' = Get-TimeStamp $_.'Actual Start Date' $CEST
        'Actual End Date' = Get-TimeStamp $_.'Actual End Date' $CEST
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "D:\1_tmp.csv" -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```